# Problems with connecting to CE database

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-2008, .net-4.0

Ive got error that provider cannot be found on my client app when trying to connect to CompactEdiction database file. When I was testing this app on my dev machine where sql server 2008 was installed everything was ok.

There is .net installed (3.5 and 4.0) and sp3 (windows xp). Do you know what am I missing to run it? There is problem with providers ...

In application catalogue there are files copied:

```
System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll
System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity.dll
sqlceca35.dll
sqlcecompact35.dll
sqlceer35EN.dll
sqlceme35.dll
sqlceoledb35.dll
sqlceqp35.dll
sqlcese35.dll
```

In app config I have such an entry:

```
<configuration>
    <system.data>
            <DbProviderFactories>
                <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5"/>
                <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=3.5.1.0, Culture=neutral"/>
            </DbProviderFactories>
        </system.data>
```

error is:

```
 error 0004: Could not load System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity.dll. Reinstall SQL Server Compact
```

and server should not be installed, thats the requirement

When there is no entry in the appConfig the error message is:

```
 The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid. ---> System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
   at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetFactory(String providerString)
```

In connection string provider is:

```
provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5
```

Comment: To start at the beginning: what provider is listed in the connectionstring?

Comment: I ve edited my question to answer your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that there is not more DLL's for SQL Compact that needs to be copied?

Also there is a new version of SQL Compact out, a 4.0 i think - maybe it will help to upgrade to that one. It's a long shot, but you'll never know ;)

**EDIT:**
Look at this site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326.aspx it states that there is seven dll files to copy over.

Comment: I need to have System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity.dll cause Im using entity frameowrk :)